# Insulating an access violation in unmanaged code

Tags: c#, clr, tesseract

I have a C# program (WPF) in which I am using the Tessnet OCR library (v2) to occasionally perform some non-essential OCR tasks.  I have heard that the library has some leaks and once in a while the program will crash from an access violation (Attempted to read or write protected memory).  I am wondering if there is any way to 'insulate' the OCR object or call so that I can simply catch an exception and re-create the object without having the program terminated, possibly even free-up any memory it has wasted.

Comment: Have you tried ABBYY SDK?

Comment: Access violations in native code are not recoverable.  You will need to run it in a separate process and talk to it with standard .NET interop like a pipe, socket or WCF.  Keep that simple so your own process can recover from the heart attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [`HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute.aspx) attribute to the method that throws access violation. This attribute:

> Enables managed code to handle exceptions that indicate a corrupted
>   process state.

For more information read [Handling Corrupted State Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx) article.